# Bonvolu analizi la strukteron de la frazo

Tags: grammar, meaning

> La signifon kaj uzon de *krokodili* oni povas kompreni nur en la
> kunteksto de la sociaj normoj de la lingvokomunumo, **kie estas virto
> utiligi ĉiujn eblojn ekzerci sin en Esperanto**. (Lindstedt, J. 2016. Ĉu
> infana Esperanto estas natura Esperanto?, p210)

Ĉu oni povas reskribi la dikigitan frazon tiumaniere?: "...kie virto estas utiligi ĉiujn eblojn [kaj] ekzerci sin en Esperanto". Se mia reskribo malpravas, kion signifas la supre  menciita dikigita frazo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la kunteksto:

- komunumo = loko, kie (io estas)
- en tiu loko estas virto
- virto = utiligi ion
- kaj tiu io estas "ebloj ekzerci" = ebloj de ekzerc(ad)o

Tie ne povas esti "kaj", ĉar tio ne estas listo de du agoj - utiligi kaj ekzerci. Tio estas sola ago - utiligi.

- eblo ekzerci = ekzerceblo, eblo ekzerci sin = sinekzerceblo

Do, ni povas reesprimi tion tiel:

- ..., kie estas virto utiligi sinekzerceblon en Esperanto.
- ..., kie estas virto de utiligo de sinekzerceblo en Esperanto.
- ..., kie estas virto de utiligo de eblo de sinekzerc(ad)o en
  Esperanto.

La sifikson -ad- vi povas uzi laŭ via deziro. Ĝi devas nur emfazi, ke la ago ekzerci ne estas unufoja - ĝi estas daŭra.

Nu, se tiu rezonado helpu al vi deĉifri la sencon.